# Synk: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: javascript, npm

I've just started to have **Synk Protect** throw *"self signed certificate in certificate chain"* when I run `npm install` on a project of mine. Can anyone give me some pointers on how I find which of the 984 packages in my project is causing this error?

```sh
> eslint-config-adjunct@4.8.11 snyk-protect /Users/dave.bradshaw/dev/eslint-config-adjunct
> snyk protect

self signed certificate in certificate chain

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! eslint-config-adjunct@4.8.11 snyk-protect: `snyk protect`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the eslint-config-adjunct@4.8.11 snyk-protect script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following:

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm binding
```